# Why does java springboot print an empty json in the browser?

Tags: java, json, list, spring-boot, rest

The Java Rest Api prints on http://localhost:8080/books

```
[{},{},{}]
```

instead of the booklist object. I use a main method a book_controller and a book model. Firstly I add a couple of books in the list in the method getbooks() and then I return them as a list.

Why does this happen?

application.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication (exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Lab6NosApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Lab6NosApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Book_controller.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;

@Controller
public class Book_controller  implements ErrorController, Serializable {

@GetMapping("books")
public @ResponseBody List<book> getbooks() {
    List<book> bookList = new ArrayList<book>();
    bookList.add(new book(1,"lokesh","gupta"));
    bookList.add(new book(2,"lokesh","gupta"));
    bookList.add(new book(3,"lokesh","gupta"));

    java.lang.System.out.print(bookList);

    return bookList;
}

  @RequestMapping("/error")
  @ResponseBody
  public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
      Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
      Exception exception = (Exception) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
      return String.format("<html><body><h2>Error Page</h2><div>Status code: <b>%s</b></div>"
                      + "<div>Exception Message: <b>%s</b></div><body></html>",
              statusCode, exception==null? "N/A": exception.getMessage());
  }

  @Override
  public String getErrorPath() {
      return "/error";
  }
}
```

Book.java

```
public class Book {

   public Book(Integer id, String title, String author) {
      super();
      this.id = id;
      this.title = title;
      this.author = author;
   }

   private Integer id;
   private String title;
   private String author;

   //getters and setters

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Employee [id=" + id + ", title=" + title
            + ", author=" + author + "]";
   }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try to remove `@JsonSerialize` from your controller and rename `book` to `Book` and `book_controller` to `BookController` to follow some basic Java naming conventions

Comment: Thank you for the idea rieckpil! I changed the code and updated the text above but unfortunately nothing changed in the endpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see it empty because your Book class doesn't have public getters or properties, so the serializer won't be able to access it's values.

Add getters to your Book class:

```
public Integer getId(){
    return this.id;
}
public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
}
public String getAuthor(){
    return this.author;
}
```

You can also improve your code, with better naming such as BookController instead of Book_controller. Have a look at java naming conventions. 
Finally, take a look at a @RestController.  If you use @RestController, you don't need to have @ResponseBody